# Why is VSCode showing two definitions for a variable when clicking Command + click on variable name in Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

While in an Angular template (html file) and I Command + click (on a Mac) on a variable name I'm getting the "peek" window showing two definitions for that variable and asking me to click on one.  However, the variable is only defined once so, as I understand it, it should be navigating to the variable definition in the ts file.  I haven't found this issue anywhere else, but I have a hard time believing I'm the only one that would be experiencing it.  Is it a configuration issue that I'm not aware of, perhaps?

I'm including two images showing the same definition for the same variable twice on the "peek" window.[image]

Comment: Are both listed definitions in the same `.ts` file, or is one of them in the `.js` file? It's possible that VSC is indexing `.js` files when it shouldn't be.

Comment: They are both pointing to the same definition in the same file.  In fact, if you click on either definition in the peek window it takes you to the same ts code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with the [Angular Language Service](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/90205079d72c7bb7def1a8928d76b26ee02bcc5f/packages/language-service).

You can report it here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues